# Have read this patent a few times and just don't understand what the invention is?

Tags: intellectual-property

So I have been reading patent [US8010108B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8010108B2/en?oq=US8010108B2) out of interest and it seems to list a lot of things the invention might do, rather than will do, and also it doesn't seem to say what it actually is? Generally just very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Technology questions are off topic for this site so this question may get closed. However, what I will advise is to focus on the claims. Here is claim 1:

> 1. A base station supporting a radio link handover in a cellular communication system, the base station comprising:
>
>    means for receiving
>      a radio link handover initiation message from a network element for a
>      radio link supporting a communication between the base station and a
>      user equipment;
>
>    determining means for determining a handover switch
>      delay; setting means for setting a characteristic of a radio link
>      handover acknowledge message in response to the handover switch delay;
>      and
>
>    means for transmitting the radio link handover acknowledge message
>      to the network element;
>
>    wherein the determining means are arranged to
>      determine the handover switch delay in response to a data discard
>      measure of a previous radio link handover for the base station.

The description in the patent should enable the claims, so read it with in the context of this claim and it may become clearer. Patents are written to be comprehensible by people educated in the field of the invention so there is no guarantee that a lay person will understand it. The patent evidently is a method for handling the handover that happens when you move from one cell tower to another during cellular communications. Its really outside my field of expertise to describe it beyond this.